# Vue.js CSS animation not working correctly when using v-if

Tags: javascript, vue.js, animation, vuejs2

Currently, using the latest version of Vue.js in my Laravel application. The expected result is when the user click on a button, it will show a certain div with the page content, and it will show a fade up animation. Specifically, what I want it to do, is when a button is clicked, the page will show and a fade-up animation will show every time I switch between pages.

**The problem**

I'll use the example below to simplify my problem. When the user clicks on the button with the `@click='productsPageBtn'` it shows the animation. When I click on the dashboard (the default) `@click='dashboardPageBtn'` it does not show the animation. But when I click back on the productsPageBtn is does work again and shows the animation again.

They both work in the same way, with a `v-if` and a `:class` when the button is clicked, it will add the animation class. The dashboard animation does show when it's loaded first on the page, but does not show the animation when I click from products to dashboard.

How am I able to fix this so that when I click on dashboard, it will also show the animation instead of just products?

Thank you in advance for any help.

HTML

```html
<div id="app">
  <button @click="dashboardPageBtn" class="">Dashboard</button>
  <button @click="productsPageBtn">Products</button>

  <div v-if="page == 'dashboard-page'" id="dashboard" class="" :class="{'content-fade-up-animation' : page == 'dashboard-page'}">
      <h1 class="top-menu-header-title">Dashboard</h1>
  </div>

  <div v-if="page == 'products-page'" id="product" class="" :class="{'content-fade-up-animation' : page == 'products-page'}">
    <div class="mt-10 text-4xl mb-10">
      <h1 class="top-menu-header-title">Test</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      page: "dashboard-page",
      headerTitle: "Dashboard"
    };
  },
  methods: {
    productsPageBtn(e) {


      this.page = "products-page";
      this.headerTitle = "Products";
    },

    dashboardPageBtn() {
      this.page = "dashboard-page";
      this.headerTitle = "Dashboard";
    }
  }
});
```

CSS

```
.content-fade-up-animation {
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    opacity: 0;
    animation-name: fadeInUp;
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeInUp;
}

/* Content fade up animation */

@keyframes fadeInUp {
    from {
        transform: translate3d(0,40px,0)
    }

    to {
        transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
        opacity: 1
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeInUp {
    from {
        transform: translate3d(0,40px,0)
    }

    to {
        transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
        opacity: 1
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you delcare two class props on the divs (class and :class)?

Comment: I realized that the `:class` was not needed, and works the same with just adding a normal class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like following snippet, with v-show and removing class when not shown `:class="page == 'dashboard-page' ? 'content-fade-up-animation' : ''"`:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      page: "dashboard-page",
      headerTitle: "Dashboard"
    };
  },
  methods: {
    productsPageBtn() {
      this.page = "products-page";
      this.headerTitle = "Products";
    },
    dashboardPageBtn() {
      this.page = "dashboard-page";
      this.headerTitle = "Dashboard";
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.content-fade-up-animation {
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  opacity: 0;
  animation-name: fadeInUp;
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeInUp;
}

/* Content fade up animation */

@keyframes fadeInUp {
  from {
    transform: translate3d(0,40px,0)
  }

  to {
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeInUp {
  from {
    transform: translate3d(0,40px,0)
  }

  to {
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    opacity: 1
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="dashboardPageBtn">Dashboard</button>
  <button @click="productsPageBtn">Products</button>
  <div v-show="page == 'dashboard-page'" id="dashboard" :class="page == 'dashboard-page' ? 'content-fade-up-animation' : ''">
    <h1 class="top-menu-header-title">Dashboard</h1>
  </div>
  <div v-show="page == 'products-page'" id="product" :class="page == 'products-page' && 'content-fade-up-animation'">
    <div class="mt-10 text-4xl mb-10">
      <h1 class="top-menu-header-title">Test</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for.